# Show message when user is connected laravel 6*

Tags: r, laravel, authentication

I want to show an alert after log in in laravel 6* , how can this be done

idk what to use in Auth/LoginController.php

Comment: please write more information

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for the replys,

For people who want a solution that work for me.I used event listen for login.

Right here the [full simple tutoriel](https://www.marknotes.fr/docs/docs/Development/Web/Laravel/3.%20Concepts/10.%20Events/2.%20Listening/2.%20Login/index.html) to add message alert when login with event listen in laravel

If you want to know more about listen event there is the [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/events) for it :)

Answer (score 0):

you can pass messages with session after login then prints it the landing page. You can read the documentation of laravel then the section is .... [#Flash Data](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/session).
also, you can show alert using Javascript or basic modal or simple bootstrap message...